# Automating sending of emails

Tags: python-3.x

I need help to put in my body content into the email. The content for the body for the email resides in a tab in excel which contains words and tables. I wan them to be in the email body and not as attachments.

Dont know where to start

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a programming service. Please show us what you have tried and where you are stuck. This way the community can help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For operating with excel files I recommend you [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) library and probably [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) library for sending emails. If you provide some code I can help you more.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Accepted! Sorry new to this!

Answer (score 1):

you might want to try using the [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library. For sending emails use [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) library. You can extract data from the excel sheet using openpyxl and send mail using smtplib.